# IR Receiver RC5 with Pic12F1572

Tags: pic, uart, decoder, receiver, infrared

I am building an IR Receiver with PIC12F1572 with receiver module TSOP2438
My objective of this project is to receive a data by remote control and send it to PC via UART..
I have done the code and I am testing it I can send the normal value through the UART but Somewhereis wrong so that I can not receive the hex values regarding the commands of remote control
Can anyone see my code and tell where I am goping wrong?
Here is my code

```
 void main(void)
{   
    OSCILLATOR_Initialize();          // 0x78 for Fosc = 16Mhz 
    PIN_MANAGER_Initialize();         //All port pins Digital and input
    EUSART_Initialize();
    INTCONbits.IOCIF = 0;            // Interrupt on-change Flag
    INTCONbits.PEIE = 1;            //SEt Peripheral Interrupt
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;             //Set Global Interrupt 
  //while(!OSCSTATbits.HFIOFS);     //Check here or wait here to OSC stable/ 0.5% accuracy

    TRISAbits.TRISA2 = 1;           //Configure R1 as input

 // uint16_t Input_buffer [20];

  EUSART_Write(0x40);             // 0x40 = @ some flag


   while(1)
  {
    count = 0;
    //while((IR_PIN));                //IR_PIN receives an IR signal its output pin goes from logic 1 to logic 0
                                    //which causes the microcontroller to start reading the IR signal using the function. decode()
    EUSART_Write(0x41); 
   //while(IR_PIN);

    if(Decode())                    //check if RC5 decoding- new data is arrived
    {

        EUSART_Write(0x42); 

        toggle_bit = bit_test(IR_Code, 11);
        address = (IR_Code >> 6) & 0x1F;
        command = IR_Code & 0x3F;

        EUSART_Write(toggle_bit);
        EUSART_Write(address);
        EUSART_Write(command);

        EUSART_Write(0x43);


    }
  }
}

/*----------*/
uint8_t Measure_space()
{
  TMR0_Initialize();

  while(IR_PIN && (count < 2000))
    count = TMR0_ReadTimer();               //Read timer value and store it in count value
  if((count > 1999) || (count < 700))
    return 0;                               //0 = If width is out of range
  if(count > 1200)
    return 1;                               //1 = If width is long
  else
    return 2;                               //2 = If the width is short
}

uint8_t Decode()
{
  uint8_t i = 0, check;
  mid1:
  check = Measure_Pulse();
  if(check == 0)
    return FALSE;
  bit_set(IR_Code, 13 - i);
  i++;

  if(i > 13)
   return TRUE;

  if(check == 1)
    goto mid0;
  else
    goto start1;

  mid0:
  check = Measure_space();
  if((check == 0) && (i != 13))

    return FALSE;

  bit_clear(IR_Code, 13 - i);
  i++;

  if(i > 13) return TRUE;

  if(check == 1)
    goto mid1;
  else
    goto start0;

 start1:
  check = Measure_space();
  if(check != 2)
    return FALSE;
  goto mid1;
  start0:
  check = Measure_Pulse();
  if(check != 2)
    return FALSE;
  goto mid0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because you are sending Hex value without converting to string. If you want to print this Hex value in PC terminal, First you have to convert it to ASCII string.

Comment: Thanks @user7424291,,I will implement

Comment: Can you all give me Up vote please?? I can not post a question anymore...